# Apache POI Exception A part with the name '/docProps/core.xml' already exists

Tags: java, android, xml, excel, apache

The below code is to compare two files (one is .xls file and other is .xlsx file) and generate a difference file eg.) diff.xlsx file, where it highlights the difference of the compared file. when I execute this code I am getting the apache poi exception.

```
**Exception**: **org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Fail to save: an error occurs while saving the package : A part with the name '/docProps/core.xml' already exists : Packages shall not contain**


package com.shorenstein.report;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import com.shorenstein.util.CellValues;
import com.shorenstein.util.EnvironmentConfig;
import com.shorenstein.util.ReportDetail;
import com.shorenstein.util.ResultDetails;
import com.shorenstein.util.ScenarioResultDetails;

public class ExcelComparator {

public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println("###########################"); 
    ResultDetails resultDetails = new ResultDetails();
    String fold1 = "C:\\download1\\";
    String fold2 = "C:\\download2\\";
    ExcelComparator ex = new ExcelComparator();
    resultDetails = ex.compareFiles(resultDetails, fold1, fold2, "rx_cm12_Recoverable_Expense");
    System.out.println("###########################");
}
public ResultDetails compareFiles(List<EnvironmentConfig> environmentConfigList){
    EnvironmentConfig environment1 = environmentConfigList.get(0);
    EnvironmentConfig environment2 = environmentConfigList.get(1);
    return compareFiles(environment1, environment2, null);
}
public List<ResultDetails> compareFiles1(List<ReportDetail> reportDetailsList){

    List<ResultDetails> listOfReportDetails=new ArrayList<ResultDetails>();
    for(ReportDetail reportDetailLoop:reportDetailsList){
        String nameOfReport=reportDetailLoop.getReportFileName();
        EnvironmentConfig environment1=reportDetailLoop.getSourceEnvironment();
        EnvironmentConfig environment2=reportDetailLoop.getDestinationEnvironment();

        ResultDetails compareFiles=compareFiles(environment1, environment2, nameOfReport);
        listOfReportDetails.add(compareFiles);
    }

    return listOfReportDetails;
}
public ResultDetails compareFiles(EnvironmentConfig environment1,EnvironmentConfig environment2,String nameOfReport){
    String fold1="C:\\download1\\";
    String fold2="C:\\download2\\";
    ResultDetails resultDetails = new ResultDetails();
    resultDetails.setEnvironment1(environment1);
    resultDetails.setEnvironment2(environment2);
    resultDetails = compareFiles(resultDetails,fold1,fold2,nameOfReport);
    return resultDetails;
}
public ResultDetails compareFiles(ResultDetails resultDetails,String folder1, String folder2,String nameOfReport) 
{
    String fileToCompare1 = null;
    String fileToCompare2 = null;
    ScenarioResultDetails scenarioResultDetails  = null;

    File folder1Obj  = new File(folder1);

    File[] filesInFolder1= listFilesAndFolders(folder1);
    File[] filesInFolder2= listFilesAndFolders(folder2);

    if(filesInFolder1.length == 0 || filesInFolder2.length == 0){
    }else{
        for(int i=0;i<filesInFolder1.length;i++)
        {
            fileToCompare1=filesInFolder1[i].getName();
            fileToCompare2= fileToCompare1;     //filesInFolder2[i].getName();       

            if(!(new File(fileToCompare2).exists())){
                if(fileToCompare2.endsWith("xls")){
                    fileToCompare2 = fileToCompare2.replace(".xls",".xlsx");
                }else if(fileToCompare2.endsWith("xlsx")){
                    fileToCompare2 = fileToCompare2.replace(".xlsx",".xls");
                }
            }

            if(fileToCompare1.endsWith(".xls") || fileToCompare1.endsWith(".xlsx"))
            {
                scenarioResultDetails = new ScenarioResultDetails();
                scenarioResultDetails.setIndex((i+1));
                scenarioResultDetails.setName("Scenario " + (i+1));
                scenarioResultDetails.setGeneratedFile1(fileToCompare1);
                scenarioResultDetails.setGeneratedFile2(fileToCompare2);
                String fileName1 = folder1 + fileToCompare1;
                String fileName2 = folder2 + fileToCompare2;
                try {
                    scenarioResultDetails = compareCellValues(fileName1, fileName2,scenarioResultDetails);

                    resultDetails.addScenarioResultDetails(scenarioResultDetails);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    fileToCompare1 = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(fileToCompare1,"utf-8");
                    fileToCompare2= java.net.URLDecoder.decode(fileToCompare2,"utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }   
    return resultDetails;
}
private static File[] listFilesAndFolders(String directoryName){
    File directory = new File(directoryName);
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
    for (File file : fList){
        try {
            FileUtils.moveFile(file, new File(java.net.URLDecoder.decode(file.getAbsolutePath(),"utf-8")));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    fList = directory.listFiles();
    return fList;
}
private ScenarioResultDetails compareCellValues(String file1, String file2,ScenarioResultDetails scenarioResultDetails){
    FileInputStream fis;
    CellValues cellValues =  null;
    HSSFSheet sh = null;
    HSSFWorkbook wrb =null;
    XSSFWorkbook wrb_2 = null;
    String fileDiff= file2.replace(".xls","_diff.xls");
        System.out.println();
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file1);
        try{    
            wrb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
        }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
            //System.out.println(file1 + "  Not downloaded successfully hence skipping this file comparision");
            scenarioResultDetails.setResult(false);
            scenarioResultDetails.setResultText("File Corrupted");
            return scenarioResultDetails;
        }
        FileInputStream fis_2= new FileInputStream(file2);
        try {
            wrb_2 = new XSSFWorkbook(fis_2);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            //System.out.println(file1 + "  Not downloaded successfully");
            scenarioResultDetails.setResult(false);
            scenarioResultDetails.setResultText("File Corrupted");
            return scenarioResultDetails;
        }
        CellStyle style = wrb_2.createCellStyle();
        Font font = wrb_2.createFont();
        font.setColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
        style.setFont(font);
        style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.YELLOW.index);
        style.setFillBackgroundColor(HSSFColor.YELLOW.index);
        style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);

        int numbeoOfSheets1 = wrb.getNumberOfSheets();
        int numbeoOfSheets2 = wrb_2.getNumberOfSheets();
        for(int sheetIndex =0;sheetIndex<numbeoOfSheets1 && sheetIndex<numbeoOfSheets2 ;sheetIndex++){//TODO:handle for diff no. of sheets
            sh=wrb.getSheetAt(sheetIndex);
            XSSFSheet sh1 = wrb_2.getSheetAt(sheetIndex);
            int noOfRowsSheet1= sh.getLastRowNum();
            int noOfRowsSheet2= sh1.getLastRowNum();

            // Coloring of mismatch rows
            if(noOfRowsSheet1 < noOfRowsSheet2){
                for(int vRow = noOfRowsSheet1; vRow < noOfRowsSheet2-1; vRow++){
                    //System.out.println("going to highlight " + vRow + " th row");
                    sh1.createRow(vRow).setRowStyle(style);
                }
            }
            if(noOfRowsSheet1 > noOfRowsSheet2){
                for(int vRow = noOfRowsSheet2+1; vRow < noOfRowsSheet1; vRow++){
                    //System.out.println("going to highlight " + vRow + " th row");
                    sh1.createRow(vRow).setRowStyle(style);
                }
            }
            //-- Coloring of mismatch rows

            //System.out.println("Number of Rows>>>>>>>>>>>"+noOfRowsSheet1);
            String cell1Value= null;
            String cell2Value=null;
            HSSFCell cell1 = null;
            XSSFCell cell2 = null;

            for(int vRow=0; vRow<=noOfRowsSheet1;vRow++){
                HSSFRow rw= sh.getRow(vRow);
                XSSFRow rw1= sh1.getRow(vRow);
                int noOfColSheet1= sh.getRow(vRow).getLastCellNum();
                int noOfColSheet2;
                try {
                    noOfColSheet2 = sh1.getRow(vRow).getLastCellNum();
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    System.out.println("Row not found : Going to create new row of number : " + vRow);
                    rw1 = sh1.createRow(vRow);
                    noOfColSheet2 = 0;
                }

                // Coloring of mismatch columns
                if(noOfColSheet1 < noOfColSheet2){
                    for(int vCol = noOfColSheet1+1; vCol <= noOfColSheet2; vCol++){
                        //System.out.println("going to highlight " + vCol + " th column in Row : " + vRow);
                        rw1.createCell(vCol).setCellStyle(style);
                    }
                }
                if(noOfColSheet1 > noOfColSheet2){
                    for(int vCo2 = noOfColSheet2+1; vCo2 <= noOfColSheet1; vCo2++){
                        //System.out.println("going to highlight " + vCo2 + " th column in Raw : " + vRow);
                        rw1.createCell(vCo2).setCellStyle(style);
                    }
                }

                for(int vCol=0; vCol<noOfColSheet1;vCol++)
                {

                    System.out.println("vCol>>"+vCol + "--vRow>>"+vRow);
                    cell1 = rw.getCell(vCol);
                    cell2 = rw1.getCell(vCol);
                    //System.out.println("cell1>>"+cell1 + "--cell1>>"+cell1);
                    if( null != cell1 ){
                        cell1Value= cell1.toString();
                    }
                    if( null != cell2 ){
                        cell2Value= cell2.toString();
                    }
                    if((null == cell1Value && null != cell2Value )|| (null!= cell1Value && null == cell2Value ) || (null != cell1Value && cell1Value.compareTo(cell2Value)!=0))
                    {
                        cellValues = new CellValues();
                        cellValues.setValue1(cell1Value);
                        cellValues.setValue2(cell2Value);
                        cellValues.setCellRow(vRow);
                        cellValues.setCellColumn(vCol);
                        scenarioResultDetails.addDifference(cellValues);

                        XSSFCell cellDiff = rw1.getCell(vCol);
                        if( null == cellDiff){
                            cellDiff = rw1.createCell(vCol);
                        }
                        cellDiff.setCellStyle(style);
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        //System.out.println("********* throwing FileNotFoundException ************* ");                
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        //System.out.println("********* throwing IOException ************* ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    FileOutputStream fileOut=null;
    try {
        fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileDiff);

        wrb_2.write(fileOut);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try {
            if(null != fileOut ){fileOut.close();}
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }

    if(scenarioResultDetails.getDifferencesList().size() > 0){
        scenarioResultDetails.setResult(false);
        scenarioResultDetails.setResultText("Not Matched");
        scenarioResultDetails.setDiffExcel(fileDiff);
    }else{
        scenarioResultDetails.setResult(true);
        scenarioResultDetails.setResultText("Matched");
    }
    return scenarioResultDetails;
}

public static void openFile(String fileName){
    ReportGenerator.getDriver().get("file://"+fileName);
}
```

}

**Exception:**

```
org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Fail to save: an error occurs while saving the package : A part with the name '/docProps/core.xml' already exists : Packages shall not contain equivalent part names and package implementers shall neither create nor recognize packages with equivalent part names. [M1.12]**

at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:503)

at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.save(OPCPackage.java:1425)

at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:201)

at com.shorenstein.report.ExcelComparator.compareCellValues(ExcelComparator.java:393)

at com.shorenstein.report.ExcelComparator.compareFiles(ExcelComparator.java:176)

at com.shorenstein.report.ExcelComparator.main(ExcelComparator.java:51)
Caused by: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidOperationException: A part with the name '/docProps/core.xml' already exists : Packages shall not contain equivalent part names and package implementers shall neither create nor recognize packages with equivalent part names. [M1.12]

at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.addPackagePart(OPCPackage.java:878)

at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:448)
```

Comment: Have you hit as bug - http://sourceforge.net/p/docfetcher/bugs/987/ ? try changing to lower stable or latest version and test your code?

Comment: @SheetalMohanSharma thanks for your response. can you suggest me on the version number so that i can try that. I have tried poi 3.9,3.11 which dosen't help me.  In the sourceforge.net/p/docfetcher/bugs/987 the issue is still not closed it is open.

Comment: I have worked with 3.8 but not sure if had used the same code. I cant try your code now, will check later today

Comment: OK thank you. It will be very helpful if you can try and give me solution later today.